# unzipping an html link with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, zip

I have an HTML web page with many download links in a table. I have isolated the path to my desired zips. They all contain an .xlsx file but sometimes other files.

1. Is there a way to avoid downloading the zips and directly accessing the files inside?
2. If I do need to download them, how can I track where the zips have been downloaded to? (So I can extract the .xlsx)

I am currently looking into `zipfile` and `requests` for solutions. `zipfile.extract` needs the path of the zip file, but I don't know exactly where the script will download to. `requests` gives a response object, but how do I prompt it to download?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to avoid downloading the zips and directly accessing the files inside?

Generally speaking : no. A web server serves files in a file system, not in a zip archive.

> If I do need to download them, how can I track where the zips have been downloaded to? (So I can extract the .xlsx)

If not specified, the location is the current directory, the one the script has been launched in.